# Visual Svn Server: How to restrict edit by specified IP Address

Tags: apache, svn, visualsvn-server, svn-server

I want to enable only a specific IPAddess to edit (add, delete, update...) my visual svn server, but all others IPAddess must be able to read...

I believe it is necessary a change like this in the file `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%conf\httpd-custom.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Location /svn>
    # write access
    <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
      Order deny,allow
      deny from all
      Allow from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
    </LimitExcept>
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

but do not know well visual svn server. what is the right way?

`Visual SVN Server 3.2 x64` is installed in `Windows 2008 R2 Server x64`

**UPDATE from VisualSvn support**

> Such feature is not available in VisualSVN Server 3.2 out-of-the-box,
>   however we consider the possibility to implement it in future
>   versions. [...] Generally speaking, it is possible to implement
>   IP-based restrictions via modifying httpd-custom.conf file, however we
>   strongly discourage to take this approach. VisualSVN Server has
>   "SVNPathAuthz short_circuit" option enabled, which dramatically
>   improves authorization performance. The option has a limitation,
>   though: server configuration mustn't rely on other authorization
>   modules such as "authz_host_module" (which is responsible for IP-based
>   checks), otherwise you will encounter unexpected behavior with
>   authorization. On the other hand, if you disable "short_circuit" you
>   will definitely notice performance degradation when running
>   authorization-intensive operations against you repositories (such as
>   running `svn log`, `svn checkout`, `svn export, etc or running a
>   graphical repository browser such as the one TortoiseSVN client
>   provides)

Comment: While this may be on-topic here at StackOverflow, you'll likely get a better response on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) as your question seems to be concerned primarily with server configuration.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk thanks for the tip. I made the request on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/852940/visual-svn-server-how-to-restrict-edit-by-specified-ip-address) . Should I delete it from StackOverflow ?

Comment: I'd leave it in case someone does happen to answer it here.  If you receive an answer on your SuperUser question first, then I would delete it.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk You probably mean serverfault.com, not SuperUser. Since this is server administration question.

Comment: @SimoneNigro First of all I recommend you contact VisualSVN support team: they will help you or at least will add one more vote for this feature request.

Comment: @IvanZhakov I tried to contact their [support](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/feedback/?vsvn-server=), but I got a `An application error occurred on the server`

Comment: @SimoneNigro You may contact using support@visualsvn.com in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's no built-in support for that in SVN, you may want to look for a workaround.

You could configure SVN server to use authentication, then allow only selected authenticated users/groups to do commits and leave everyone for read-only access. Security can be hardened in IIS and, SSL/TLS can be used easily and you could even detect and block brute force password attempts, if that's your main reason to consider IP filtering.

**If for some reason IP filtering is a must**, I'd suggest having another SVN Server instance (that runs on a different IP port) and do a repository copy to that instance (use svn dump on main instance, then svn load on your read-only instance 2). Then have your firewall allow commiters (that are filtered by IP) access the main SVN server, and all other IPs can access the read-only SVN server instance.

With svn dump and load you actually copy everything - all commits, history, comments, etc. You could do that as often as you like, and you can also bind these actions to the post-commit hook, to have it happen after every commit.